# Django nested Transaction.atomic not rolled back

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have two logically connected instance in two different data bases. I want them both to be saved or rollbacked. But if I raise an exception in an outer block - nested `Transaction.atomic` will not rollback, but why?

From documentation:

> **atomic** blocks can be nested. In this case, when an inner block
>   completes successfully, its effects can still be rolled back if an
>   exception is raised in the outer block at a later point.

```
def __commit_to_db(self, mesure, mdm_mesure):
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            mesure.save()
            with transaction.atomic(using='mdm'):
                mdm_mesure.save()
            raise Exception('oops')
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        raise
    except BaseException as error:
        MainLoger.log_error(error)
    return
```

Comment: For database error handling you can use Exception instead of BaseException.Its a better practice to narrow down possible errors and handle only those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transactions are a database-level feature. So although you're nesting the Python code, each database is actually getting its own transaction independent of the other. There are no nested transactions that span databases in Django.

You'll have to restructure your code in some way. For example, putting your code inside both `atomic()` blocks would work:

```
try:
    with transaction.atomic():
        with transaction.atomic(using='mdm'):
            mesure.save()
            mdm_mesure.save()

            # neither transaction will commit
            raise Exception('oops')
except Exception:
    pass
```